# Visual Studio 2017 publishing .net core mvc app errors with 'the command "dotnet bundle" exited with code 1'

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017, dotnet-bundle

I've just migrated a .net core MVC project which was working fine and publishing fine in Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio 2017. Problem is that I cannot publish the app at all, I just get a publish failure and the error 'the command "dotnet bundle" exited with code 1'

I've found a few post on other sites and stackoverflow but they all suggest adding this to the .csproj file (see [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655803/the-command-dotnet-bundle-exited-with-code-1-vs-2017-publish-asp-net-core-we))

```
<ItemGroup>
   <DotNetCliToolReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="2.4.337"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

But despite adding this I still get the same error!?!

I can't seem to find anything else to try... don't suppose anyone has anymore or any other suggestions I've missed?

P.S. Not loving Microsoft's backward step (imho) from project.json files to the old XML style .csproj files!

Comment: After you've added that to the csproj file, can you run `dotnet bundle`. Also PS csproj is way better than you might think, just get used to it and you'll be fine.

Comment: I can run "dotnet bundle" on other directories fine but strangely i get a 'No executable found matching command "dotnet bundle"' when I try to run from the specified applications folder!?! I'm guessing that might be because its still got some old VS2015 tooling referenced or something maybe?

Comment: What do you mean by "specified applications folder"?

Comment: The folder where my application code is (e.g. c:\projects\mysolution\myproject)

Comment: So you have a csproj file in that folder that contains the `DotNetCliToolReference` entry?

Comment: Yes I do indeed ;-)